# store data in mysql after reading from excel files

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i am trying to make o program where i will read the data from excel files and i will store them in a database. I am using eclipse as editor and mySQL. I am using APACHE POI to read the excel files and JDBC for the connection. The excel files have the structure as shown below:

```
ID    NAME   SALARY   STREET
---   ----   ------   -------------
321   TIM    1254     14 avenue
121   PAUL   1265     28h oktovriou
432   NICK   4521     papaflessa
```

I have of course plenty of such files which contains many more rows and columns. The purpose of my program is to read the data, create table named as the name of the excel file and the fields of each table to be the first rows of the excel file. Afterwards the values will be the rest data of the excel file.
In the code below i have managed to read them, show the data in the console. Afterwrds i am trying to call a database with JDBC but there i have problem when i create the table.

```
try
            {
                String[] allFields;
                String createTableStr = "CREATE TABLE" + createTableStr
                   + "(" + org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(allFields,
                   ",") + ")";
```

Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!:)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class exam1 {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unchecked" })
    static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filename = "C:\\Users\\Efi\\Documents\\test5.xls";

        List sheetData = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                List data = new ArrayList();
                   while (cells.hasNext()) {
                   HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                   data.add(cell);
                   }
                   sheetData.add(data);
            }

                   } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   } finally {
                   if (fis != null) {
                   fis.close();
                   }
                   }

    showExcelData(sheetData);


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    HashMap<String, String> tableFields = new HashMap();
          for (int i=0; i<sheetData.size();i++){
          List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
              for (int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){
                Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);
                 if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());

                  }else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {


                  System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
              } else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
            System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    }
                if (j < list.size() - 1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
                    }}}
                    }

    private static void showExcelData(List sheetData) {

        }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private HashMap parseExcelData (List sheetData){

            HashMap<String,Integer> tableFields = new HashMap();
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(0);
            for (int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){
                Cell cell=(Cell) list.get(j);
                tableFields.put(cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getCellType());
        }

            return tableFields;

        }



    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unchecked", "unchecked", "unchecked", "unused" })
    private String getCreateTable(String tablename, HashMap<String, Integer> tableFields){
        Iterator iter = tableFields.keySet().iterator();
        String str="";
        String[] allFields = new String[tableFields.size()];
        int i = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()){
        String fieldName = (String) iter.next();
        Integer fieldType=(Integer)tableFields.get(fieldName);

        switch (fieldType){
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        str=fieldName + "INTEGER";
        break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        str= fieldName + "VARCHAR(255)";
        break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        str=fieldName + "INTEGER";
        break;
            }
        allFields[i++]= str;
        }
        return str; 
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kainourgia","root", "root");
            Statement  stmt = con.createStatement();
            try
            {
            System.out.println( "Use the database..." );
            stmt.executeUpdate( "USE kainourgia;" );
            }
            catch( SQLException e )
            {
            System.out.println( "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() );
            System.out.println( "SQLState:     " + e.getSQLState() );
            System.out.println( "VendorError:  " + e.getErrorCode() );
            }
            try
            {
                String[] allFields;
                String createTableStr = "CREATE TABLE" + createTableStr
                   + "(" + org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(allFields,
                   ",") + ")";

                System.out.println( "Create a new table in the database" );
                stmt.executeUpdate( createTableStr );
                }
            catch( SQLException e )
            {
            System.out.println( "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() );
            System.out.println( "SQLState:     " + e.getSQLState() );
            System.out.println( "VendorError:  " + e.getErrorCode() );
            }
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
            System.out.println( ((SQLException) e).getSQLState() );
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: "there i have problem when i create the table." - and the problem is? tell us which exception you're getting...

Comment: Nothing, none exception. Only in editor it's shows me that i have mistake.

Comment: I realize this is your first question here, so I think you should read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how your questions ought to be formulated. Ideally we shouldn't have to spend time *finding* the issue, i.e. you say what the issue is, and we try to figure out how to solve it ;). I bet your compiler/editor is telling you what's wrong there. Anyway, you're creating and assigning the String createTableStr with itself, when it has no content yet. Also you are concatenating a newly created String array allFields, which will be empty - but I believe you are aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting a compilation error here:

```
            String[] allFields;
            String createTableStr = "CREATE TABLE" + createTableStr
               + "(" + org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(allFields,
               ",") + ")";
```

You are getting this error because you have used `allFields` without initializing it. You cannot use a local reference variable without initializing first. Initialize it first and then use it. Moreover, you should initialize it with values of the column names that you read from the Excel file, so that your table is created correctly.

Also, I see that you are casting e to `SQLException` here:

```
       catch( Exception e )
        {
        System.out.println( ((SQLException) e).getSQLState() );
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You shouldn't do this, because if the e was an instance of `SQLException`, it would be been caught by the first catch block. It has reached the second catch block suggests that it is not an instance of `SQLException`. So, it will produce a `ClassCastException` when you try to cast it to `SQLException`.

Comment: any idea how i will do it?

Comment: You will have to read the column names from the excel file, and then assign them to the String array. Initialize it by `allFields = new String[numberOfColumns];`, considering you have a maximum of 20 columns in your table. Then initialize individual objects by using `allFields[1] = "ID";` and so on.

Comment: I would like to do it programatically. I mean i will initialize it but then the initialization of the each field to happen by the array list that i have stored the data. How i will do this?